# Validation rule on lead to prevent conversion

Tags: validation, leads, conversion

Was hoping someone could help with the following:

I would like to prevent a user from Converting a lead that does not have 
1. at least 1 alpha character (upper or lower case)  - (A-Z) or (a-z)
2. Or at least one numeric character (0-9) & and least one Alpha character (A-Z) (a-z).
Does not need both just one or the other (1 or 2).

I am trying to add this validation to the Company field on leads to prevent conversion of leads with companies that have any special characters.

I believe it would look similar to this but this is not working the way I described it above.

AND(
  IsConverted,
  NOT(REGEX(Company, '[A-z]+'))
)
OR
  AND(IsConverted,
  NOT(REGEX(Company, '[A-z]+'),
  NOT(REGEX(Company, '[0-9]))),
)

Comment: Thanks, I had that setting turned on, however I don't believe my formula is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular expression to meet your requirement :

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d).+$
```

Where

```
^               - Start of String
(?=.*[a-zA-Z])  - use positive look ahead to see if either lower or uppercase exists
(?=.*\d)        - use positive look ahead to see if number present
.+              - gobble up the entire string
$               - End of string
```

You nmay need to enable validation rule capability on lead conversion by contacting salesforce support.

Comment: Thanks, I had that setting turned on, however I don't believe my formula is correct. How do I en corporate what you provided into my validation rule?

Comment: Put it inside your `REGEX` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [setting for what you want](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176187&language=en_US). It is called "Require validation for Converted Leads." You may have to contact support to enable it.

Comment: Thanks, I had that setting turned on, however I don't believe my formula is correct. –  J.Y.